# Where is the FTP support for Google Chrome and Internet Explorer 8?

Tags: browser, permissions, ftp

I tried to upload files via FTP but ran into problems. Are modern day browsers no longer supporting FTP "write" capability? I managed to use Dreamweaver to FTP the files successfully.

Comment: I personally hope that FTP goes the way of the dodo.  Re: modern browsers FTP support; I'd assume there shouldn't be any compatibility problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't find anything anywhere about FTP uploading in Internet Explorer past version 6. My guess is that they are limiting support for it (standard FTP) due to its lack of security.

Tons of sites still link to downloads on FTP servers, so we will continue to see browsers support FTP downloads for a long time. As for uploading, the trend seems to be that you should have a dedicated client now, which makes the security concerns less transparent. I second the FileZilla recommendation.

Maybe someday we'll see FTPS support in browsers.

**Update:** I tried FTP Upload with IE8. It displayed a hyperlinked list of files, but had this message at the top: "To view this FTP site in Windows Explorer, click Page, and then click Open FTP Site in Windows Explorer." I followed those instructions and I was able to upload and download in Windows Explorer. I guess that is how it works now, whereas IE 6 had it integrated.

Comment: the last time I tried filezilla it came bundled with a whole bunch of shit I didn't want. is that still the case? 

as long as we're making recommendations, I like flashfxp.

Comment: I downloaded it a few weeks ago and it's just the client, afaik.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a problem with whatever web interface is provided by the server. Try a dedicated FTP client like Filezilla.