# Large files upload in web browser

Tags: php, file, upload, ftp, webdav

This is the first time for me asking a question. Hope you'll be able to help me.

Problem: my chef wants our enterprise application to have a module which allows customers to upload very large files to our server.

Infrastructure: php 5.x / mysql client-server app

Well known problems:
-HTTP session time out
-Upload limit in terms of number of files and file size

Rules:

-The solution mustn't use any applet (java, flash, ...), neither any browser plugin.
-The solution should allow users to upload any type of files, from simple images to very large files of any other type.
-For security reasons, we don't want to change the settings in the php.ini file, neither in any .htaccess file to allow the app uploading larger files.
-If a pre-backed solution exists, it should be opensource and possibly free of charges.
-Integration with AJAX functionalities and progress bar visualisation are heavily welcome.

Possible solutions (tell me if it's possible, and if it isn't, why?):

-Access by FTP using some javascript library in the browser
-Access by WebDAV using some javascript library in the browser

**Any other solutions that respect the above given rules is also welcome**

I know, I'm asking for a very hard thing to find.

Comment: there are a large number of file upload scripts using various technologies available, have you looked at any?

Comment: Yes, I did. The problem is that crappy problems with sessions and file size. I looked up for an ftp uploader solution, but it seems that such applications have the same session timeout problems as http does.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for isn't currently possible. The only technology for uploading files which is currently available in all widely used browsers is standard HTTP form uploads, which you've already rejected as a solution. All other solutions available require Java or Flash, or use browser JavaScript capabilities (local file access) which are not fully standardized, nor universally available.

You'll need to relax some of your requirements.

Comment: I've also seen, that some browsers support XForms using the PUT http verb. But I honestly didn't understand very well the difference between uploading a file with the put and the post verb.

Comment: None of the major web browsers (MSIE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari) support XForms. In any case, `PUT` form submissions will likely have the exact same limitations as normal file uploads.

Answer (score -1):

Create an iframe or frame, or browser-window that offers access to the server via FTP. Allows users to drop files there for those browsers at least who support FTP.

Comment: That… doesn't make sense. Pointing an `<iframe>` to a `ftp://` URL doesn't magically make the browser capable of uploading content via FTP. (Most modern browsers cannot.) Nor does it provide any way to resume uploads in the case of a timeout, or display progress of an ongoing upload.

Comment: Popular browsers do, http://www.hosting.com/support/upload/browser-ftp, http://www.oakton.edu/resource/it/ftp/index.htm - but you just need to go 5-10 years back, offer your users a download if they don't have it any longer. See as well: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2813869/367456

Comment: Right, and installing a web browser that's at least ten years old is hardly a viable option today. At that point you'd be better off just installing a real FTP client!

Comment: @duskwuff: yeah, why not? I once created and admin interface where users could upload large stuff via FTP. They then could manage/select their uploads within the browser then. Worked like a charm for the uploaders. Those who didn't wanted to install an FTP client, a java applet was offered. As browsers have never been made for large uploads (which aren't trivial anyway), this only slowly evolves. HTTP is not FTP.